# Where is the file copy dialog in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, file-browser

I used the file copy dialog in VS 2010 to selectively push web files to a production server. The only tool I can find in VS 2012 that is similar is the Web Publish Activity dialog. It forces you to fully synchronize your entire site. That is not realistic because I don't always want to deploy all site changes at once.

Where can I find/enable the old file copy tool that had folder synchronization?

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not appropriate here ("Please post a list of links I can consider" or "Please do my research for me and post links" type questions.) There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "off topic". Good luck.

Comment: @Ken, thanks for the vote of confidence. The reality is that I've done a ton of research and installing software. I can't find a piece of software that completes my dev workflow like pre-VS2012. I guess I'll change my post to appease Big Brother.

Comment: Do you still have the VS2010 setup? If so maybe you can find the macro command it issues.

Comment: Insults (like "Big Brother") are not appropriate here, and can result in your account being suspended or banned. SO works by keeping things strictly on topic, and relies on its users to do so. The [faq] clearly indicates that, and if you have complaints about the guidelines here please post them on [meta] and ask to have them changed. The posts I linked in my first comment clearly explain why the question isn't appropriate here; I didn't write them (or the responses to them). (While you're visiting the [faq], you might read the section on acceptable behavior here as well.)

Comment: BTW, your edited question is much more appropriate for SO, and I don't have an issue with it. (I do have an issue with the comment still, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the button to get to the Website Copy tool was removed from the Solution Explorer tool window, but it still exists under the Website nav menu. I never knew it was there, my bad.